# Every longbow-wielding peasant's finest hour?

Tags: opening, english-opening

It's called the English opening - some reference to Howard Staunton and the perambulations of the mid to late 19th Century; but, does the variant name refer to the Ancien Regime charging up a muddy hill, or the propensity to loose masses of arrows then get stuck in with the sword and shield after?

```
[Title "English Opening: Agincourt Defense"]
[fen ""]
[Event "Rated Bullet game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/AeUmXNuE"]
[Date "2023.09.15"]
[White "heallan"]
[Black "bsalman"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2023.09.15"]
[UTCTime "00:22:41"]
[WhiteElo "1381"]
[BlackElo "1446"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+6"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-6"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "120+0"]
[ECO "A13"]
[Opening "English Opening: Agincourt Defense"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. Nf3 e6 2. c4 d5 3. cxd5 exd5 4. d4 Be6 5. Nbd2 Bb4 6. a3 Bxd2+ 7. Bxd2 Nf6 8. e3 Ne4 9. Ne5 Nxd2 10. Qxd2 O-O 11. Bd3 Nc6 12. Nxc6 bxc6 13. Qe2 g6 14. Qf3 Qd7 15. Rc1 Bf5 16. Bxf5 Qxf5 17. Qxf5 gxf5 18. O-O Kh8 19. Rxc6 Rac8 20. b4 Rg8 21. Rfc1 Rg7 22. Rxc7 Rcg8 23. g3 h5 24. Rxa7 h4 25. Rcc7 hxg3 26. fxg3 Re8 27. Rxf7 Rxf7 28. Rxf7 Rxe3 29. Rf8+ Kg7 30. Rxf5 Rxa3 31. Rxd5 Ra4 32. Rb5 Kf7 33. d5 Ke7 34. Rb6 Kd7 35. d6 Ra1+ 36. Kg2 Ra2+ 37. Kh3 Rd2 38. Rb7+ Kxd6 39. Rb6+ Kc7 40. Rb5 Kc6 41. Rg5 Rd4 42. Rg4 Rd5 43. Rg6+ Kb5 44. Rg4 Rh5+ 45. Kg2 Rf5 46. h4 Rh5 47. Rg5+ Rxg5 48. hxg5 Kxb4 49. g6 Kc5 50. g7 Kd6 51. g8=Q Ke7 52. Qg4 Kf6 53. Qf4+ Ke6 54. g4 Kd5 55. g5 Ke6 56. g6 Ke7 57. g7 Ke6 58. g8=Q+ Kd7 59. Qf6 Kc7 60. Qgg7+ Kc8 61. Qff8# 1-0
```

So, why is this response to the English Opening called the Agincourt Defense?

2k2Q2/6Q1/8/8/8/8/6K1/8 b - - 6 61

Answer (score 5):

> does the variant name refer to the Dukes of Burgundy charging up a muddy hill, or the propensity to loose masses of arrows then get stuck in with the sword and shield after?

Alas, no. It is more prosaic. At Agincourt the French faced the English and here white plays c4, the English, and black responds with e6 and d5, the French. So, we have the French against the English.